# Cannot access last linked list array element

Tags: java

I new in Java and trying to run some tests. I cannot use the .getLast() function as its showing error and also cannot seem to create the method. What am I doing wrong.
Here is my partial code. I am trying to create the getLast method which is failing.

Here is the error The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ListOfNVersion03PartA.

```
 */
public class ListOfNVersion03PartA
{   
    private int thisNumber;              // the number stored in this node
    private ListOfNVersion03PartA next;  // forms a linked list of objects

    private final int nodeID;            // a unique ID for each object in the list

    private static int nodeCount = 0;    // the number of list objects that have been created

    /**
     * @param  num   the value to be stored in this object
     */
    public ListOfNVersion03PartA(int num)
    {
        thisNumber = num;
        next = null;

        ++nodeCount;
        nodeID = nodeCount;

    } // constructor(int num)

    /**
     * @param  num   the multiple values to be stored in the list, in that order
     */
    public ListOfNVersion03PartA(int [] num)
    {
        this(num[0]);  // in this context, "this" invokes the other constructor        

        for (int i=1 ; i<num.length ; ++i)
            insertLast(num[i]);

    } // constructor(int [] num)

    /**
     * @return     the number of elements stored in this list 
     */
    public int getListSize()
    {
        return nodeCount;

    } // method getListSize

    /**
     * @return     the last element in the list
     */
    public int getLast()
    {
        int y =  next[nodeCount-1];
        return y;

    } // method getLast

    /**
     * prints this object
     */
    public void printNode()
    {
        System.out.print("[" + nodeID + "," + thisNumber + "]->");

    } // method printListNode

    /**
     * prints the tail of a list
     */
    private void printListTail()
    {
        printNode();

        if ( next != null )
            next.printListTail();

    } // method printListTail

    /**
     * prints the contents of the list, in order from first to last
     */
    public void printList()
    {
        printNode();

        if ( next != null )
            next.printListTail();

    } // method printList

    /**
     * This method is NOT examinable in this test.
     * 
     * prints the contents of the list, in order from first to last, and
     * then moves the cursor to the next line
     */
    public void printlnList()
    {
        printList();
        System.out.println();

    } // method printlnList

    /**
     * @return     the number of times the element occurs in the list
     * 
     * @param  element   the element to be counted
     */
    public int countElement(int element)
    {
        return 999;

    } // method countElement 

    /**
     * @return     the number of times the replacement was made
     * 
     * @param  replaceThis   the element to be replaced
     * @param  withThis      the replacement
     */
    public int replaceAll(int replaceThis, int withThis)
    {
        return 999;

    } // method replaceAll

    /**
     * @return a reference to the first object in the list that contains the parameter value, or null if it is not found
     * 
     * @param  findThis   the value to be found
     */
    public ListOfNVersion03PartA findUnSorted(int findThis)
    {  
        // This algorithm is known as "linear search"

        if ( thisNumber == findThis )
            return this;

        if ( next != null )
            return next.findUnSorted(findThis);

        return null;

    } // method findUnSorted 

    /**
     * @return     the reference to the object containing the smallest element in the list
     */
    public ListOfNVersion03PartA minRef()
    {
        // add and/or modify code to complete the method 
        ListOfNVersion03PartA minOfTail;

        if ( next == null )
            return this;

        minOfTail = next.minRef();

        if ( thisNumber <= minOfTail.thisNumber )
            return this; 
        else
            return minOfTail;

    } // method minRef

    /**
     * Inserts an element in the last position. The pre-existing elements in the
     * list are unaffected.
     * 
     * @param  newElement   the element to be inserted
     */
    public void insertLast(int newElement)
    { 
        if ( next == null )
            next = new ListOfNVersion03PartA(newElement);
        else
            next.insertLast(newElement);

    } // method insertLast



} // class ListOfNVersion03PartA
```

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting?  Please copy and paste it into the question.

Comment: What is `int y =  next(nodeCount-1);` supposed to do?

Comment: I'm guessing the error is on the line with `next(nodeCount-1);` Well you didn't show any method named "next" but guessing from the error it doesn't take an int as a parameter.  (Edit: HINT: show the code for the method "next".)

Comment: I understand the error is there but I dont know how to access the array. I am thinking next is the array list  so next[nodeCount-1] should display the the element of that array number.

Comment: It isn't an array list, it's a method.  Show. The. Code.

Comment: I have attached the full code. I am trying to just do the getLast method complete.

Comment: What's `next[nodeCount-1]` supposed to do? `next` is an instance, not an array.

Comment: how do I access JUST the array? I tried  ListOfNVersion03PartA(nodeCount-1) but it doesnt work. It says expression expected after (

Comment: What array?! The only array there is an array in the ctor that shoves everything into the linked list.

Comment: I think there's something wrong here.  The error shouldn't be telling that `next()` takes an integer parameter.  Unless you've accidentally imported a method from some other place, which is possible.  Show your imports too, or at least check them for a static import of a method `next()`.  Otherwise, your compiler gives very fishy error messages.

Comment: I have not imported anything. If i use int x = next.getLast(); return x; I get null pointer exception error. Which should not be the case since I am creating a list and successfully return the list size using my listSize method. What is the correct way to finish the getLast method?

Comment: You seem to be confused with linked list and array. In your code, you created a class `ListOfNVersion03PartA`, that essentially represent a single node (element) in a linked list, and it should hold a pointer to the next element in the linked list. (`private ListOfNVersion03PartA next;` However, the way you are using `next[nodeCount-1]` is treating `next` as an array, but it is actually just another instance of class `ListOfNVersion03PartA` (not an array so you cannot call it with `next[nodeCount-1]`.